# console schema update and new tables

Tags: cakephp

I'm trying to update mysql database with cake schema. In old database, I had 2 tables. And in the new one, which I trying to update to, there are 2 new tables.

When I perform `cake schema update`, it throws an error:

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'db.new_table' doesn't exist

It's clear, because those 2 new tables doesn't exist, so CakeConsole should create them first.

I'm using version 2.3. Is there any options to correct this bug? Or is it solved in later versions?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I upgraded to latest version (2.5.5). And now, schema update works perfectly. Because there is some changes at lines 379-393 of [SchemaShell.php](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.5.5/lib/Cake/Console/Command/SchemaShell.php#L379) which checks for existence of tables.

```
if (empty($table)) {
    foreach ($compare as $table => $changes) {
        if (isset($compare[$table]['create'])) {
            $contents[$table] = $db->createSchema($Schema, $table);
        } else {
            $contents[$table] = $db->alterSchema(array($table => $compare[$table]), $table);
        }
    }
} elseif (isset($compare[$table])) {
    if (isset($compare[$table]['create'])) {
        $contents[$table] = $db->createSchema($Schema, $table);
    } else {
        $contents[$table] = $db->alterSchema(array($table => $compare[$table]), $table);
    }
}
```